Error with openssl while deploying with GitHub Actions
I have an issue while deploying with https://github.com/marketplace/actions/capistrano-deploy. Here's my workflow:
name: Deploy with Capistrano

on:
  push:
    branches: [main]
  workflow_dispatch:

jobs:
  deploy:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v3
      - uses: ruby/setup-ruby@v1
        with:
          ruby-version: 2.6.10
          bundler-cache: true
      - uses: miloserdow/capistrano-deploy@v3
        with:
          target: staging
          deploy_key: ${{ secrets.DEPLOY_ENC_KEY }}
          enc_rsa_key_pth: config/deploy_id_ed25519_enc
          capistrano_commands: '["deploy:npminstall", "deploy:ssh"]'

error in pipeline
When I make it manual everything works, but in Actions it doesn't. Does somebody know where the problem can be if my secrets 100% right?
Tried to make another pipeline to check everything:
name: Deploy with Capistrano

on:
  push:
    branches: [main]
  workflow_dispatch:

jobs:
  deploy:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v3
      - uses: ruby/setup-ruby@v1
        with:
          ruby-version: 2.6.10
          bundler-cache: true
      - name: Check if encrypted file exists
        run: |
          if [ ! -f config/deploy_id_ed25519_enc ]; then
            echo "Encrypted file not found!"
            exit 1
          fi
      - name: Decrypt SSH key
        run: |
          mkdir -p ~/.ssh
          echo "${{ secrets.DEPLOY_ENC_KEY }}" | openssl enc -d -aes-256-cbc -md sha512 -salt -out ~/.ssh/id_ed25519 -k "${{ secrets.DEPLOY_ENC_KEY }}" -a -pbkdf2
          chmod 600 ~/.ssh/id_ed25519
          ssh-keyscan -H dexin.magazento.com >> ~/.ssh/known_hosts
      - name: Install dependencies
        run: bundle install
      - name: Deploy with Capistrano
        run: bundle exec cap staging deploy

it returns that config file exists but error exists too.
